# React Native: How to nest project under a subfolder?

Tags: react-native

I have a plain old react native project that I'm trying to reorganize and dump into a `mobile/` folder like this:

```
▾ mobile/
  ▸ __tests__/
  ▸ android/
  ▸ app/
  ▸ ios/
  ▸ node_modules/
    app.json
    index.android.js
    index.ios.js
    package.json
    yarn.lock
▸ redux/
▸ web/
```

However, after doing this, deleting node modules and reinstalling, and then running `yarn start` I see this:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It was because I forgot to move the .babelrc file into `mobile/`